# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{k}$ by induction

Tags: summation, induction

**Question:**

Prove the following statement by induction for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k + 1}}{k} = \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{k}$$

**My Attempt:**

*Base Case:* For $n = 1, \sum_{k=1}^1 \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^1 \frac{1}{k} = 1.$

*Inductive Step:*

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} + \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{2n} + \frac{(-1)^{2n+2}}{2n+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{2n + 1}
\end{align}

The issue here is that I'm not really sure how to go from that equation to $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{k}$.
I'd really appreciate it if you could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove by induction that $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} = \sum_{m=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}, \qquad \forall n \in N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576521/prove-by-induction-that-sum-k-n12n-frac1k-sum-m-12n-frac) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B2n-1%7D%5Cfrac%7B(-1)%5E%7Bk%2B1%7D%7D%7Bk%7D%3D%5Csum_%7Bk%3Dn%7D%5E%7B2n-1%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1). Note your problem is equivalent by replacing $n$ with $n+1$ to get ...

Comment: (cont.) $\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{k}$, where the last term on each side is $\frac{1}{2n+1}$, so they may be subtracted to get the expression in the proposed duplicate question. Note there are also other duplicate, or basically duplicate, questions, e.g., [Summation of reciprocals](/q/1941385), [Having problem in last step on proving by induction $\sum^{2n}_{i=n+1}\frac{1}{i}=\sum^{2n}_{i=1}\frac{(-1)^{1+i}}{i} $ for $n\ge 1$](/q/1298016), [How do you prove this without using induction?](/q/1755083), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Problem with proof by induction](/q/3337210), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to write $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}{\frac{1}{k}} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}{\frac{1}{k}}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}{\frac{1}{k}}+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}$

The last two terms will be canceled by the remaining terms in your derivation.